# localhost using docker compose up not working

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

I am trying to test a simple server endpoint on my local machine when running `docker compose up` but it does not seem the ports are exposed when running docker this way. If I just do a `docker build` and `docker run` I can use localhost to get a successful endpoint call but not when I use my docker compose file.

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
  services:
    simple:
      build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: simple
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    environment:
      - SOMEKEY=ABCD
      - ANOTHERKEY=EFG
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.5

ARG VERSION
ARG SERVICE_NAME
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt 
COPY app /app/app
COPY main.py /app/
CMD ["python", "./app/main.py"]
```

And then my main.py file

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=3000, host="0.0.0.0")
```

`docker compose up` does not seem to want to expose to local host.

What I use with build and run that does expose:
`docker build -t test-test .`
`docker run -p 3000:3000 test-test`

Is there a way to expose the port to localhost with `docker compose up`?

Comment: The port should be 80:3000 in the docker compose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for ports is HOST:CONTAINER. The port on the container is 3000, so you've got it backwards.

```
version: '3'
  services:
    simple:
     build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: simple
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    environment:
      - SOMEKEY=ABCD
      - ANOTHERKEY=EFG
```

Comment: Wonderful! Such a dumb mistake from me... Thanks!